# Using jQuery .each() to infinitely loop over elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of elements like this

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="block active">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need a function to infinitely loop on these elements (block) moving the active class from one to the next. I've looked at using .each() for this but I don't really understand how to use it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want to add some class to these DOM elements Right ?

Comment: infinitely loop  when?

Comment: And when should this action happen? a button click or something?

Comment: so you want a slider, is is that hard to write "slider"

Comment: as suggested by @madalin slider is a good option, you can also run a setInterval and in the callback method find the next sibling and toggle the class on both current active block and its sibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do it in an interval, this is pretty easy in your case:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    var index = $(".block.active").removeClass("active").index();
        index = index + 1 >= $(".block").length ? 0 : ++index;

    $(".block:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("active");
}, 500);
```

```css
div.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block active">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `++index% blockLength` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to loop over all elements. You just have to do following:

1. Fetch element with `active` class.
2. Check for existence of `next/previous` element based on action.
3. If exists, remove active class from current element and assign it to corresponding element.

#### Carousel

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/gxz609zz/)

```js
$("#btnPrev").on("click", function() {
  var els = $(".block.active");
  if (els.prev() && els.prev().hasClass('block')) {
    els.removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
  }
})

$("#btnNext").on("click", function() {
  var els = $(".block.active");
  if (els.next() && els.next().hasClass('block')) {
    els.removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block active">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="btnPrev">Prev</button>
<button id="btnNext">Next</button>
```

#### Ticker

As commented by [@atul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385619/atul), if you are looking for something like a news ticker, which goes on and on, you can try something like this:

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/gxz609zz/2/)

```js
function nextTicker(){
 var els = $(".block.active");
  els.removeClass("active");
  if(els.next() && els.next().hasClass('block')){
   els.next().addClass("active");
  }
  else{
   $(".block:eq(0)").addClass('active');
  }
}

var interval = setInterval(nextTicker, 1000);

// To stop flooding 
setTimeout(function(){
  window.clearInterval(interval)
}, 20*1000)
```

```css
.active{
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="block active">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in the question he has mentioned as "infinitely loop on these elements (block)" but in you case user has to click on the next prev btns. I think he want something like news ticker, where the content becomes visible one by one periodically

Comment: In that case, @eisbehr's answer is appropriate. Still I'll update my answer to show both cases.

Comment: @atul I have updated my answer according to your comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just a hint, you can replace `if(els.next() && els.next().hasClass('block')){` with `if(els.next(".block")){`

Comment: And you can compress the `.next()` calls from three into only one: https://jsfiddle.net/gxz609zz/3/ :)